# Best hook to use to save a new node when a node is saved

Tags: 7, nodes

I want programatically create a new node of type B (status message),
immediately after a node of type A (e.g. gallery post) is added (or updated).

Looking at [this recipe](http://fooninja.net/2011/04/13/guide-to-programmatic-node-creation-in-drupal-7/), I see that I will have to add hook_node_insert inside my module and call node_save to save the new node. But on the comments to the hook_node_insert docs [ndvo](https://api.drupal.org/comment/47063#comment-47063) claims I can't call node_save in the middle of another node_save operation. So what is the best approach to use?

Answer (score 1):

There is no hook which is called AFTER the node is saved. No POST-SAVE hook.

But calling `node_save` within `hook_insert` actually works. The warnings were false:

So I ended up with something like:

```
function MYMODULE_node_insert($node) {
  if ( $node->type == 'blog_post') {
    MYMODULE_insert_statuspost($node);
  }
}

function MYMODULE_insert_statuspost($n) {
  global $user;
  $node = new stdClass();
  $node->title = "New blog post $n->title";
  $node->type = "statuspost";
  node_object_prepare($node); /* Sets some defaults. 
     Invokes hook_prepare() and hook_node_prepare(). */
  $node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE; // Or e.g. 'en' if locale is enabled
  $node->body[$node->language][0]['value'] = 
    "New blog post: " . l($n->title, "node/$n->nid") . " has been posted");
  $node->uid = $user->uid;
  $node->status = 1; //(1 or 0): published or not
  $node->promote = 0; //(1 or 0): promoted to front page
  $node->comment = 2; // 0 = comments disabled, 1 = read only, 2 = read/write
  $node = node_submit($node); // Prepare node for saving
  node_save($node);
  drupal_set_message( "Status post with nid " . $node->nid . " saved!\n");
}
```

[Here](http://fooninja.net/2011/04/13/guide-to-programmatic-node-creation-in-drupal-7/) is a full commented code to programatically create a node.